# Paramiko Expect doesn't raise an error on timeout

Tags: python, paramiko, cisco

I try to detect an enable prompt on a Cisco router. By using the print parameter I can see that the router is not in priviliged mode. But the expect just times out, prints "EXCESS TIME RECV_READY TIMEOUT, did you expect() before a send()" and continues with the script. How can I get it to raise an error? I had a look into the SSHClientInteraction class of paramiko-expect and would assume that at least this "interact.expect(ena_prompt, timeout=10)" should raise an error. I also tried 5s and 15 seconds.

Python version is: Python 3.9.8 64bit
Paramiko Expect version is: 0.3.5

Could somebody point into the probably obvious direction to get this solved?

```
def check_nhrp_neigh(hostaddress, hostadm, hostpw):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    print('Trying to connect to {} ...'.format(hostaddress))
    ssh.connect(hostname=hostaddress, username=hostadm, password=hostpw, timeout=40, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
    interact = SSHClientInteraction(ssh, timeout=10, display=True)
    # program will wait till session is established and rtr returns admin prompt
    interact.expect(ena_prompt, timeout=10)
    interact.send('term len 0')
    interact.expect(ena_prompt)
    interact.send('sh ip nhrp')
    interact.expect(ena_prompt)
    nhrp_neigh = interact.current_output_clean
    regex = r'NBMA address: (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)'
    matches = re.findall(regex, nhrp_neigh, re.MULTILINE)
    ssh.close()
    print('Got NHRP neighbors from {}'.format(hostaddress))
    print(matches)
    return matches
```

Comment: Oh my.  Martin, thanks for correcting -.-